# How get camera orientation in NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera2, arcore

I'm getting the NDK_Image from ARCore on the NDK side of the project.
My AImage is coming rotated because of the camera orientation.

**How could I get the value of the camera orientation inside the NDK**?

In the Camera NDK docs I found this [ACAMERA_JPEG_ORIENTATION](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera#group___camera_1gga49cf3e5a3deefe079ad036a8fac14627a25400e923ec347e3d28a50be1d27940f)

It even give a sample of code:

```
private int getJpegOrientation(CameraCharacteristics c, int deviceOrientation) {
    if (deviceOrientation == android.view.OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return 0;
    int sensorOrientation = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
    // Round device orientation to a multiple of 90
deviceOrientation = (deviceOrientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
    // Reverse device orientation for front-facing cameras
    boolean facingFront = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
    if (facingFront) deviceOrientation = -deviceOrientation;
    // Calculate desired JPEG orientation relative to camera orientation to make
    // the image upright relative to the device orientation
    int jpegOrientation = (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;
    return jpegOrientation;
}
```

But it don't explain how to use, and I cannot find the library for `CameraCharascteristics`.

Would be a nice a sample about how to get the camera orientation in the NDK. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample code in Java is there by mistake.

From C++, you can call **ACameraManager_getCameraCharacteristics()** with tag [ACAMERA_SENSOR_ORIENTATION](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera#group___camera_1gga49cf3e5a3deefe079ad036a8fac14627a3b5093323983d5aebbb7c6f26375af93) and tag [ACAMERA_LENS_FACING](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera.html#group___camera_1gga49cf3e5a3deefe079ad036a8fac14627a75167ab558d54b5845434cd6e908e79a).

`OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN` is a [constant -1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html#ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN). `CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT` or [ACAMERA_LENS_FACING_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera.html#group___camera_1gga9d9b97b33432a938a25123ebad4eeec7a1fea1b8c8f34c8387a1d483657b1c6b8) is `0`.

Comment: Probably you are right, but I could not found a sample yet, how to use this. What I need to set in each parameter. If you have one sample or guide would be great. If not, don't worry, I will keep searching and comeback here to put right stick after I can use =)